# What is equivalent of useQueryState for a redux toolkit mutation?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit, redux-selector

You can get data from redux store using the redux toolkit hook `useQueryState`
 https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#usequerystate

```
const useQueryStateResult = api.endpoints.getPosts.useQueryState(arg, options)
```

this property .useQueryState exists only for queries, what to use if we want to know the result of mutation later on?

Comment: Didnt try before but seems like you can use the params of `useMutation` to use the result of the mutation across your app: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/pull/1477